# Plancherel theorem implies Fourier inversion on finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory

Let $\Pi (G)$ be the set of equivalence classes of irreducible representations of a finite group $G$. Here $d_{\pi}$ denotes the dimension of the representation $\pi\in\Pi(G)$, and $\pi_{i,j}(x)$ denotes the (i,j) matrix entry of $\pi(x).$

We define $\pi(f)=\sum_{x\in G}f(x)\pi(x)$ and we know that
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
f(1)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in\Pi(G)}d_{\pi} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\pi(f)\right)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\sum_{x\in G}|f(x)|^2=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in\Pi(G)}d_{\pi}\|\pi(f)\|^2_{HS}, 
\end{equation}
where $\|.\|$ denotes the Hilbert-Schmidt norm (the square root of the sum of the absolute value
squared of the entries).
 I try to show that (1) and (2) are equivalent. I know that (1) implies (2). How can we show that (2) implies (1)? Thanks.

Attempt: I show (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2). We define the convolution on $G$ by 
$$f*h(x)=\sum_{y\in G}f(xy^{-1})h(y)\qquad \text{for all $f,h\in C(G,\Bbb{C})$}$$
We apply the function $f*f^*$ to the equation (1) where $f^*(x):=\overline{f(x^{-1})}$. Then we have 
\begin{equation}\label{bb3}
f*f^*(1)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in\Pi(G)}d_\pi\operatorname{Tr}(\pi(f*f^*))
\end{equation}
But we have 
$$f*f^*(1)=\sum_{y\in G}f(y^{-1})f^*(y)=\sum_{y\in G}f(y^{-1})\overline{f(y^{-1})}=\sum_{x\in G}|f(x)|^2$$
and 
$$
\|\pi(f)\|_{HS}^2=\operatorname{Tr}(\pi(f)\pi(f)^*)=\operatorname{Tr}(\pi(f)\pi(f^*))=\operatorname{Tr}(\pi(f*f^*))
$$
Therefore the equation (1) becomes (2).

But how about the other implication?